# FreeBSD 14.0, Ruby on Rails deployment issues (gem sqlite3 not installing)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, freebsd

I'm trying to deploy rails in FreeBSD 14.0 and when I try to deploy a new project, using `rails new truck` command I'm receiving the following error:

```
package configuration for /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.1/gems/sqlite3-1.7.2/ports/x86_64-unknown-freebsd14.0/sqlite3/3.45.1/lib/pkgconfig/sqlite3.pc is not found
```

I just tried to correct the issue using gem bundler, or even installing the sqlite3 1.7.2 port, but without success! So I need help.